# MYSQL: Incremental Sorting of Duplicate Numbers

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by, window-functions, sql-rank

I have a table that looks like this:

| id | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |

I would like to have them sorted incrementally in some sort of loop that orders them in this fashion

| id | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 |

I believe this could be done easily with PHP however I would like to see if this can be done using SQL.

Comment: The second table of expected outcome is not displaying as a table on publishing. It does on edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `values` ORDER BY id), 
         `values`;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/WKLuQ0VX).